# Remove specific data from json file in linux

Tags: python, linux, jq, centos7

I have a json file with set of data with repeating fields. I need to remove an entry with specific data of a field.

Json file:

```
[
    {
        "targets": [
            "172.17.1.199"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "__meta_netbox_pop": "st-1742",
            "__snmp_module__": "arista_sw"
        }
    },
    {
        "targets": [
            "172.17.1.51"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "__meta_netbox_pop": "st-1754",
            "__snmp_module__": "arista_sw"
        }
    }
]
```

The json file goes on and but this is an example of the whole json file.

I need to remove an entry of `targets` with its `labels` given a data of the `target's` IP.

Input:

```
172.17.1.51
```

expected output:

```
[
    {
        "targets": [
            "172.17.1.199"
        ],
        "labels": {
            "__meta_netbox_pop": "st-1742",
            "__snmp_module__": "arista_sw"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```sh
$ jq --arg ip 172.17.1.51 'map(select(.targets | contains([$ip]) | not ))' input.json 
[
  {
    "targets": [
      "172.17.1.199"
    ],
    "labels": {
      "__meta_netbox_pop": "st-1742",
      "__snmp_module__": "arista_sw"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: How can I make it so that it accepts the labels.__meta_netbox_pop? Say `st-1754`? Output should still be the same

Comment: Okay, figured it out. Used `jq --arg store 'st-3829' 'map(select(.labels.__meta_netbox_pop | contains($store) | not ))' test.json > output.json`

Comment: @user13539846 `map(select(.labels.__meta_netbox_pop != $store))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this should do the trick:

The `target` parameter is the IP address you want to remove, while the `file_path` is the path of the json file

edit: also, don't forget to `import json` or else it won't work

```py
def remove_obj(target, file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    for obj in data:
        if target in obj["targets"]:
            data.remove(obj)

    with open(file_path, "w") as data_file:
        json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
```